# 'deferreds[...]' is null or not an object WordPress on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

Getting a JS error that stop PODs WYSIWYG fields from displaying

The page loads then then after a few seconds the following error occurs:

```
deferreds[...] is null or not an object jquery.wpcom-proxy-request.js?ver=20140113, line 7 character 190c
```

which is: `return deferreds[request.callback].promise();`

and yes `deferreds` is null.

Moreover, `request.callback` is a decimal e.g. 0.6165924936189611 which seems very strange.

The error seems to be occurring when a request is made from https://widgets.wp.com/notes/notes-widget.min.js although given the IE debugging tools I'm not entirely sure. `b.wpcom_proxy_request(...) is null or not an object notes-widget.min.js?v=20140113, line 5 character 21830`

Browser IE8 Wordpress v3.8 User logs in using WP user accounts

Comment: WordPress support has asked if JetPack is installed or any other widgets using WordPress notes. I wonder how to that out which widgets use notes?

Comment: The WordPress support team suggests this is an issue with JetPack